# MySQL subquery using same id fields twice from one table for description

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1242

`SELECT move.idItem, item.description, 
(
SELECT location.location_name as movedFrom FROM move, location 
WHERE move.idlocationFrom = location.idlocation
) AS movedFrom, 
(
SELECT location.location_name as movedTo FROM move, location 
WHERE move.idlocationTo = location.idlocation
) AS movedTo 
FROM move , item
WHERE move.idItem = item.idItem`

I'm trying to get the name of the location movedTo and movedFrom using the above query, which produdes  '#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row' error in PHPMyAdmin.

Description
Item movements are stored in a table called 'move'. Items can be moved from one location to another storing the location id's (location names stored in 'location' table) and item names stored in 'item' table.  movedTo and movedFrom will store the id's from the location table.

Can someone please help me with this query?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use joins instead subqueries. Something like:

```
SELECT move.idItem, 
       item.description, 
       location1.location_name movedFrom, 
       location2.location_name as movedTo
FROM move 
INNER JOIN location location1 ON move.idlocationFrom = locatio1n.idlocation
INNER JOIN location location2 ON move.idlocationTo = location2.idlocation
INNER JOIN item ON move.idItem = item.idItem
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table 1 -  cpe Table

|id | name
|----------
| 1 | cat
| 2 | dog
| 3 | mouse
| 4 | snake
-----------

Table 2 - AutoSelect

|id  | name   |  cpe1_id |  cpe2_id  | cpe3_id |
|-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | user1  |  1       |  3        | 4       |
| 2  | user2  |  3       |  1        | 2       |
| 3  | user3  |  3       |  3        | 2       |
| 4  | user4  |  4       |  2        | 1       |
------------------------------------------------

I would like to see an output of

user1 | cat   | mouse  |  snake  |
user2 | mouse | snake  |  dog    | 
..etc

 SELECT a.name, cpe1.name, cpe2.name, cpe3.name FROM AutoSelect as a
 LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe1 ON ( cpe1.id = a.cpe1_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe2 ON ( cpe2.id = a.cpe2_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe3 ON ( cpe3.id = a.cpe3_id )
```